# Toggle text with link

Tags: javascript, jquery, swap

I want to change a text within a p-tag when I click a link that is actually within the same p-tag.

**Example:**

```
var isMail = 0;
$('.switchto').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if(isMail == 0) {
        $(this).parent().html("oder doch lieber einen <a href='#' class='switchto'>Facebook Freund</a>");
        isMail = 1;
    } else {
        $(this).parent().html("oder lieber <a href='#' class='switchto'>E-Mailadresse eingeben</a>");
        isMail = 0;
    }

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<p>oder lieber <a href="#" class="switchto">E-Mailadresse eingeben</a></p>
```

Why is this not working correctly? Am I missing something? Is there an easier way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overriding the content including the original element when replacing its parent's html, so it should only work once. Try using `.on()` instead:

```
var isMail = 0;
$('body').on('click','.switchto',function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if(isMail == 0) {
        $(this).parent().html("oder doch lieber einen <a href='#' class='switchto'>Facebook Freund</a>");
        isMail = 1;
    } else {
        $(this).parent().html("oder lieber <a href='#' class='switchto'>E-Mailadresse eingeben</a>");
        isMail = 0;
    }
});
```

You can also use this shorter version:

```
var isMail = 0;
var part1 = ['oder doch lieber einen','oder lieber'];
var part2 = ['Facebook Freund','E-Mailadresse eingeben'];
$('body').on('click','.switchto',function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent().html(part1[isMail%2]+ 
            " <a href='#' class='switchto'>"+part2[isMail%2] +"</a>");
    isMail++;
});
```

[**<kbd>JSBin Demo</kbd>**](http://jsbin.com/eledac/1/edit)

Comment: This works great. Will mark that as an answer. One question: is it also possible, somehow, to disable a function on an input field within the "click"? I have a "autocomplete" on an input, that I want to disable when I click(switch) to "email". Is that possible?

Comment: @Marek123 Sure you can, just add something like: `if(isMail%2) $('yourInputSelector').attr('autocomplete','off'); else $('yourInputSelector').removeAttr('autocomplete');`

Answer (score 2):

I would add a span:

```
<p><span>oder lieber </span><a href="#" class="switchto">E-Mailadresse eingeben</a></p>
```

and do :

```
$('.switchto').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
        var state = txt == 'Facebook Freund';
        $(this).prev('span').text(state ? 'oder lieber ' : 'oder doch lieber einen ');
        return state ? 'E-Mailadresse eingeben' : 'Facebook Freund';
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ykah/5/)